# How to search for an element in Enterprise Architect 14 by GUID reference?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I´m trying to search for elements in Enterprise Architect 14 by **GUID** reference, but I didn´t find any option.

Comment: https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=25686.0

Comment: Searching Sparx' forum is still a PITA. But usually Google is helping quite a lot,,,

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SQL search definition with the following query:

```
select c.ea_guid AS CLASSGUID,c.object_type AS CLASSTYPE,c.name AS Name, c.stereotype AS Stereotype ,package.name AS PackageName ,package_p1.name AS PackageLevel1,package_p2.name AS PackageLevel2,package_p3.name AS PackageLevel3 
from ((((t_object c 
inner join t_package  package on c.package_id = package.package_id) 
left join t_package  package_p1 on package_p1.package_id = package.parent_id) 
left join t_package  package_p2 on package_p2.package_id = package_p1.parent_id) 
left join t_package  package_p3 on package_p3.package_id = package_p2.parent_id) 
where 
c.ea_guid like '<Search Term>'
```

Or you can use my free add-in [EA-Navigator](https://bellekens.com/ea-navigator/)